# License for deploying websites developed using Webmatrix into production

Tags: .net, web-applications, licensing, webmatrix

I have good experience in developing .net web apps for big clients.

I want to create a website for my own.

I am not sure whether i have to buy licence from microsoft for using any of it's .net related languages.

I know that WebMatrix is an opensource tool from microsoft.

I want to use Asp.net for building web site.

Can we move the websites developed in webmatrix directly to production without buying any license ?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need a license for publishing web sites built om ASP.NET, and you can use any of the free tools to build it. Both WebMatrix and Visual C# Express are free tools that allow you to do this.

The only license cost involved would be that of the OS you are hosting on, and if you are purchasing hosting at a hosting company, that is taken care of.